# Using VBScript GetObject in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, vbscript

I am running a third party application which runs web pages within it. The third party app includes a dll which sits on the server. Basically I am trying to replace the current VB Script that is used with C# code.

The following vbscript runs in a web page and includes a function that changes pages and works perfectly.

```
'VB Script
Set AgentDisp = GetObject("","AgentDisp.AgentDispatcher")
AgentDisp.ChangePage PageName, False
```

Now when I try the same in C# by adding a reference to this dll and running the following code on page load, nothing happens

```
// C#
var a = new AgentDisp.AgentDispatcher();
a.ChangePage("faq.aspx", false);
```

Is it something to do with the location or instance of the dll?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know C# but your code appears to be the same as CreateObject but early bound. You need to use the GetObject equiv.

GetObject works on running instances or on data files.

```
GetObject([pathname] [, class])

When this code is executed, the application associated with the specified
pathname is started and the object in the specified file is activated. If
pathname is a zero-length string (""), GetObject returns a new object
instance of the specified type. If the pathname argument is omitted,
GetObject returns a currently active object of the specified type. If no
object of the specified type exists, an error occurs.
```

Also VBScript uses late binding (ie IDispatch). You are using early binding. Shoudn't matter though.

Comment: So both examples are creating new instances of the object.

Comment: If pathname is omitted then an active class is set. If pathname is blank then a new document is created. GetObject is also in vb.net and is exactly the same as vbscript's. I can't make heads or tails out of the C# docs. I can't even see there are functions. So put GetObject in a vb module in your project.